# React Input text now being shown

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a composed input text (joining 4 input components) but i'm not being able.

Everything seems to be OK and the only way I Have been able to show the input text is placing it in the render of the main React component (cardform). In the DOM explorer (chrome) the only componet I an empty cardNumberFullField

This is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JS:

```
    class CardForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <cardNumberFullField />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function cardNumberFullField() {
    return (
        <div>
            <cardNumberInputField inputName="0" />
            <cardNumberInputField inputName="1" />
            <cardNumberInputField inputName="2" />
            <cardNumberInputField inputName="3" />
        </div>
    )
}

function cardNumberInputField(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input id={props.inputName} name={props.inputName} type="text" />
        </div>
    )
}

// Main render
ReactDOM.render(<CardForm />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React custom components always needs to be in Capitalized. So `cardNumberFullField` should be `CardNumberFullField`, `cardNumberInputField` should be `CardNumberInputField`

Check [Specifying The React Element Type](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type).

> The first part of a JSX tag determines the type of the React element.
>
> Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React
>   component. These tags get compiled into a direct reference to the
>   named variable, so if you use the JSX  expression, Foo must be
>   in scope.

```js
class CardForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CardNumberFullField />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function CardNumberFullField() {
  return (
    <div>
      <CardNumberInputField inputName="0" />
      <CardNumberInputField inputName="1" />
      <CardNumberInputField inputName="2" />
      <CardNumberInputField inputName="3" />
    </div>
  );
}

function CardNumberInputField(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input id={props.inputName} name={props.inputName} type="text" />
    </div>
  );
}

// Main render
ReactDOM.render(<CardForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: cardNumberFullField is rendered like this in HTML <cardNumberFullField /> while with capital letter it is rendered as it is written in jsx